# Javascript || Filter through UL

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to build a search input that filters through all UL's and hides the elements that don't contain the search words.

Currently it checks if the li element contains a search word, but doesn't loop all li elements to check if the search word is named.

So for example if I now have a ul with 3 li's in it. It only checks the first one and not the rest resulting in a ineffective filter system.

> **Does anyone know how i can improve my code to make it filter all li elements and hide the parent ul if it doesn't contain the search word?**

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, div;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("partners");
    li = div.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].parentElement.style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].parentElement.style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

**HTML/PHP**

```php
<div id="partners">
    <?php echo "Count: " . count($partners)."<br>"; ?>
    <?php foreach ($partners as $partner): ?>
        <ul class="partner">
            <li><b>contact name:</b><a href="#"><?php echo $partner['name'] ?></a></li>
            <li><b>Company name:</b><a href="#"><?php echo $partner['companyname'] ?></a></li>
            <li><b>Country:</b><a href="#"><?php echo $partner['country'] ?></a></li>
            <li><b>Phonenumber:</b><a href="#"><?php echo $partner['number'] ?></a></li>
            <li><b>Business:</b><a href="#"><?php echo $partner['business'] ?></a></li>
        </ul>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Changing the PHP made the  code work:

```
            <div id="partners"> 
            <ul id="myUL">
                <?php foreach ($partners as $partner): ?>
                    <li class="partner" id="">
                        <a id="a" href="#">
                            <b>Contact name:</b><h3><?php echo $partner['name'] ?></h3><br>
                            <b>Company name:</b><h3><?php echo $partner['companyname'] ?></h3><br>
                            <b>Country:</b><h3><?php echo $partner['country'] ?></h3><br>
                            <b>Phonenumber:</b><h3><?php echo $partner['number'] ?></h3><br>
                            <b>Business:</b><h4><?php echo $partner['business'] ?></h4><br>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hiding the `UL` even if one `li`'s text doesn't match.

Use `querySelectorAll`, `Array.from` and `filter`

```
var hasMatch = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( "#partners ul li a") ).filter( function(el){
   return el.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(filter); 
}).length > 0
```

Now if `hasMatch` is 0, hide the `UL`

```
if ( hasMatch == 0 )
{
   document.querySelector( "#partners ul" ).style.display = "none";
}
else
{
   document.querySelector( "#partners ul" ).style.display = "";
}
```

Comment: Hi can you explain a bit more?

I'm not sure how I would apply this to my application

Comment: Please be specific about the part that needs clarification.

Comment: I've tried to implement your code into my app, but it does not give me a result.

Comment: This doesn't help me in understanding how to help you - *but it does not give me a result*.

Comment: When I apply your code my app with my variables and I enter a name into the input field no ul get's hidden.

Comment: Please share a working fiddle that demonstrate your issue.

Comment: @Salman Some issues in selectors.... check the updated pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRVRWw

Comment: Hi I'm fiddeling around with the code, but havent gotten positive results https://codepen.io/salman15/pen/GxzxER?editors=1010